# Get dtmf input in lua script freesswitch

Tags: lua, freeswitch, dtmf

I had been working with freeswitch for the past two months. I am having an issue regarding the dtmf input taking. I am using lua scripting in freeswitch to get the dtmf input i am using the following below code:

```
digits = session:getDigits(2, "#", 5000);
```

In the above one i am getting the entered dtmf within 5 seconds and the ending character is # and size of 2. I what to know how to get dtmf input after i as soon as enter the two digits it should not wait util the timeout. In proper terms i what to move to next step after the caller enters the two digits. Is there any function to do or any solutions please?

Answer (score 2):

If max_digits(1st arg) set to 2 then it will not wait for timeout if you have pressed 2 digits. You can also try same with playAndGetDigits.